# Find PMF of $U=X+Y$

Tags: calculus, statistics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent discrete random variables such that:

P$(y)=1/3,\; y=-1,0,1$

$P(x)=1/2,\; x=2,4$

Let $U=X+Y$

Find the probability mass function of $U.$

I currently have the sum of all $y, x$ of the probability of $X$ multiplied by the probability of $Y$ but it feels wrong :S.

Thanks, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please tell us $P(U = u)$ for a couple of possible values of $u,$ so we can tell if you're on the right track. For example, do $P(U=1)$ and $P(U=3)$ have positive probability? If, so what?

Comment: @BruceET:  No I wasn't on the right track. I went back over it with a friend and we found out I was wrong.

Comment: Glad it's straightened out. Thanks for letting us know.

Comment: @BruceET, should I delete this thread or is there a way to mark it as resolved since I got the solution. I have not used this website much so far.

Comment: There is. Not quite sure how. Never did it. Maybe click 'flag' and say what you want to do. // But how about posting your own Answer? Maybe not the details of the solution, but just the results.

Comment: @BruceET, good idea thanks for the help. I answered it myself and I'll accept it once I can confirm it is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I was able to answer this myself. I calculated the MGF of X and Y then the MGF of U using those and I used the coefficients from the MGF of U and ended up with:

$P$($U$=1)=1/6

$P$($U$=2)=1/6

$P$($U$=3)=1/3

$P$($U$=4)=1/6

$P$($U$=5)=1/6

If anyone could confirm this for me or tell me why it is wrong or maybe a better way to go about it then that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer looks OK.